# Included XMLBeans .jar file uses wrong schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.HASH

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, xmlbeans

I have two intellij Maven based projects.  1st is a library that turns a bunch of .XSD files into classes with xmlbeans.  2nd is a project that imports the library and uses the xmlbean generated classes.   The 1st project generate classes are 'schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/system/sB743BF26396730AECDBC120E2F8D4B9A...' but the 2nd errors with 'Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load SchemaTypeSystem. Unable to load class with name schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.s5EFEB9AF80B80B5F805AFE83A6ADE419.TypeSystemHolder. Make sure the generated binary files are on the classpath.'

Clearly the xmlbean system hash is different,  no idea where that is coming from in the 2nd project

The library worked when I wasn't using Maven,  I rebuilt the project (cut-n-paste) into a new Maven project as I'm attempting to convert everything to Maven.

Project 1 (the library) is Maven based and I see the resulting .jar file gets installed into my .m2 local repository.  The repository .jar has the xmlbeans hash of sB743BF26396730AECDBC120E2F8D4B9A

Project 2 (the application) is Maven based and I have a dependency of the Project 1 jar file

Project 1 (the library):
 Maven pom.xml

````xml
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.crocker.integrations</groupId>
        <artifactId>broadworks</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
      <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>target/generated-classes/xmlbeans</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.*</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </resources>

    [...]

               <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>xmlbeans</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                        <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xmlbeans/.staleFlag</staleFile>
                        <verbose>false</verbose>
                        <quiet>false</quiet>
                        <javaSource>1.6</javaSource>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
    ```

    Project 2 (the application):
    ```xml
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.crocker.integrations</groupId>
                <artifactId>broadworks</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
    ```


    all of the objects resolve in intellij,  compiles clean,  runs and then barfs when trying to pull up the xmlbean.

    It is clear in the error below that the hashes are different and that is why the runtime can't find the object.   I've cleaned and rebuilt all of the project repeatedly and cannot for the life of me figure out why Project 2 gets the wrong hash.

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at webservice.broadsoft.com.ProcessOCIMessageDocument$Factory.newInstance(ProcessOCIMessageDocument.java:92)
        at com.crocker.integrations.broadworks.OCIASSession.processOCICommand(OCIASSession.java:78)
        at com.crocker.integrations.broadworks.OCIASSession.Authenticate(OCIASSession.java:106)
        at com.crocker.integrations.broadworks.Broadworks.login(Broadworks.java:23)
        at com.crocker.projects.App.main(App.java:42)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load SchemaTypeSystem. Unable to load class with name schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.s5EFEB9AF80B80B5F805AFE83A6ADE419.TypeSystemHolder. Make sure the generated binary files are on the classpath.
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(XmlBeans.java:788)
        at webservice.broadsoft.com.ProcessOCIMessageDocument.<clinit>(ProcessOCIMessageDocument.java:20)
        ... 5 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.s5EFEB9AF80B80B5F805AFE83A6ADE419.TypeSystemHolder
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(XmlBeans.java:774)
        ... 6 more

    Process finished with exit code 1
````